# Case dependent scaling of plot size in ggplot loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2, scale, geom-bar

I am running a several ggplot barplots in a loop, including added text on top of each bar. I have defined plot scale via `coord_fixed` and `expand_limits`. Unfortunately, the y-axis differs from plot to plot, so that scale settings will not fit in all cases, i.e. the text gets cut off and/or the axes get compressed. Let me illustrate:

```
period <- c(rep("A",4),rep("B",4))
group <- rep(c("C","C","D","D"),2)
size <- rep(c("E","F"),4)
value <- c(23,29,77,62,18,30,54,81)
df <- data.frame(period,group,size,value)

library(ggplot2)

for (i in levels(df$group)) 
{
p <- ggplot(subset(df, group==i), aes(x=size, y=value,  fill = period)) + 
     geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity", show.legend=F) +
     geom_text(data=subset(df, group==i), aes(x=size, y=value,label=value),
               size=10, fontface="bold", position = position_dodge(width=1),vjust = -0.5) +
     expand_limits(y = max(df$value)*0.6) + 
     coord_fixed(ratio = 0.01)

ggsave(paste0("yourfilepath",i,".png"), width=7.72, height=4.5, units="in", p)
}
```

I would like the settings of `coord_fixed` and `expand_limits` to be case sensitive, dependening on value. I have experimented with using e.g. `expand_limits(y = max(df$value * ifelse(df$value <= 50, 0.6, 1)))`, but that doesn't work in the way I had hoped. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try something like `expand_limits(y = max(df$value[df$group==i]) + 10) +`? You can replace `10` with some other arbitrarily large number that's appropriate for the text size on your screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Z.Lin's comment, I have added the `df$value[df$group==i]` argument to my `ifelse` function: `expand_limits(y = max(df$value[df$group==i] * ifelse(df$value[df$group==i] <= 50, 5, 8)))`.